# Graphic Magic how to reduce Quality

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick

I am using Graphic Magic to reduce the images

```
 gm('images/'+local_image_name).resize(223, 147, '^').gravity('Center').crop(223,147).write('images/thumb_'+local_image_name, function (err) {                                                        


});
```

Here is my code.

When i check image properties is is **40-45kb.** Also i check youtube thumb images which is of 10-12 kb and very very clear. Can we do it same.

How? Anyidea ..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you can use the `quality` method:

```
image.quality(50).write(filename,function(err){});
```

See the documentation: http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#quality

---

### Additional answer:

From the documentation, it appears that graphics magic implement chainable methods. From your code example I assumed you understood this because your code used it but I may be wrong. The code I wrote above is shorthand for:

```
var image = gm('images/'+local_image_name).resize(223, 147, '^').gravity('Center').crop(223,147);
image.quality(50).write(filename,function(err){});
```

Which can also be written as:

```
var image = gm('images/'+local_image_name);
image.resize(223, 147, '^');
image.gravity('Center');
image.crop(223,147);
image.quality(50);
image.write(filename,function(err){});
```

which can also be written as:

```
    var image = gm('images/'+local_image_name).resize(223, 147, '^').gravity('Center').crop(223,147).quality(50).write(filename,function(err){});
```

Comment: What about resize. i need to resize image as well

Comment: Yes resize it if you want? What don't you understand exactly? That methods can be chained?

Comment: gm('images/'+local_image_name).resize(223, 147, '^').gravity('Center').crop(223, 147).quality(12).write('images/thumb_'+local_image_name, function (err) {  

this gives me 64kb

Comment: i tried your code. it gives me 64 kb after quality is 12

Comment: Also check the image type (file extension). Some, like PNG or JPG compresses better than GIF